# Apply func between 2 dataframes with different indexes in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes each has column **"count"** of dtype int64 and index **"product_id"**, so I want to use handmade formula between both dataframe's index for "count" columns. I know that I can do smth like dataframe **"substraction"** but culdn't find how to use handmade function between dataframe's columns. By the way amount of rows and indexes not match exactly. I need to use function only with indexes which are the same.

Here is the example of both dataframes

```
df2_count[['count']].head()

    count
product_id  
    9014    41
    8458    11
    55522   9
    6969    8
    8840    7


df1_count[['count']].head()

        count
product_id  
    7545    12
    8866    10
    8867    10
    47196   6
    9014    5
```

---

That's what I tried to do. When I didn't find how to do what I need --> I tried to create NaN sample df where rows and columns are dataframes indexes respectively. Then iterate over each row for each column and fill the NaN sample dataframe by function's results but it seems so much mess, lots of NaN which I even don't know how to process and make it look normally for person to read.

```
data_ibs = pd.DataFrame(index=df2_count.index,columns=df1_count.index)

def formula(a, b):
    if a > b:
        ans_inc = (a-b) / b * 100
        return ans_inc
    else: 
        ans_decr = (a-b) / a * 100
        return ans_decr

for i in range(0,len(df2_count.index)):
    for j in range(0,len(df1_count.index)):
        if df2_count.index[i] == df1_count.index[j]:
            a = df2_count.get_value(df2_count.index[i], 'count')
            b = df1_count.get_value(df1_count.index[j], 'count')
            data_ibs.ix[i,j] = formula(a, b)

output_csv = data_ibs.to_csv('output.csv')
```

May someone help me how can I implement what I need more easely and more "pandasly"? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did it in more elegant way ( pandas way ). The idea is not to try apply func between different dataframes but combine it into one and then compute what you need with simple pandas in-build **apply** function

```
dff = pd.merge(df2_count, df1_count, how='outer', \
                    right_index=True, left_index=True, suffixes=('_x', '_y')).fillna(1) 
dff['mean'] = dff[['count_x', 'count_y']].mean(axis=1)
dff['sum'] = dff[['count_x', 'count_y']].sum(axis=1)
dff['count_percents'] = dff.apply(lambda row: change_percents(row['count_x'], row['count_y']), axis=1)
```

By the way, you can create one dataframe from a list of dataframes. Just attached the code that I used --> can also be helpful.

```
frames = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('csv'): 
        continue
    logging.debug(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, filename), index_col=None, names=['wallets'])
    frames.append(df)
    logging.debug(frames)
```

Hope, it will help someone :)